# rails serving a static json file returns diffrent content in browser or through a get request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a static json file I need to serve with content-type: application/json to allow some deeplinking from my rails app to the corresponding android app. For this google is expecting a url to a static file which looks like this: `domain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` and the correct content-type.

So in my rails app I have the following file `app/views/static/assetlinks.json`.

And in my routes.rb I have:

```
...

resources :static, except: [:new, :create, :edit, :show, :update, :destroy ]
get '.well-known/assetlinks.json' => 'static#assetlinks'

...
```

If i then load `domain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` in my browser it is served correctly with the header set to Content-Type: application/json. But if I use hurl.it or postman with a get request for the same URL I get a response with the .html.erb template with the assetlinks.json content baked into it and Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8.

What kind of sorcery is this? How can I make it consistent to always serve only the JSON with the correct content-type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set default format in your routes file and it will respond correctly for all request without format specify.

```
get '.well-known/assetlinks.json' => 'static#assetlinks', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure 100% but set:

```
get '.well-known/assetlinks' => 'static#assetlinks'
```

without .json

And at your controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json do .....
  end
end
```

This way it will only respond to json.

You can force it then by requesting with json format like 
domain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

You dont have to put .json in routes.rb